# Mathematica & Ubuntu 14.04. Installation complete but command not found!

Tags: 14.04, execute-command, mathematica

I just uploaded to Ubuntu 14.04, but Mathematica 10.1 is not working any more. I un-installed it and re-installed again.

```
$ sudo bash Mathematica_10.1.0_LINUX.sh
Mathematica 10.1.0 for LINUX Installer Archive

Verifying archive integrity. 
Extracting installer
/usr/NKS/Mathematica
Create directory (y/n)?
> y
Now installing...
> /usr/NKS/Mathematica
Installation complete.
```

But when I launch the software, it says

```
/usr/NKS/Mathematica$ mathematica
mathematica: command not found
```

I asked already to the StackExchnge Ask-Mathematica. They told me to verify the System Requirements, and I do, and closed my question because not relevant to the community as specific to OS and not to the software itself. Is there someone who encountered a similar problem and could, please, help me? Thank you, XXXL

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l /usr/NKS/Mathematica; echo $PATH`? You may need to run `cd /usr/NKS/Mathematica` then `./mathematica` to run it.

Comment: Great, it worked! Thanks! But do I have repeat this procedure every time? Is there any way to run it by simply clicking on the command as it was before updating to Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish what you want. I think the best method for you is to create a shortcut on the desktop called Mathematica, and just double click it to launch the program. To do this:

Open `gedit`, create a new file with the following in it, call it Mathematica.desktop, and place it on the Desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Mathematica
Comment=Launch the Mathematica program
Exec=/usr/NKS/Mathematica/mathematica
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Open a terminal and type `chmod +x ~/Desktop/Mathematica.desktop` to make it "executable" (i.e. double-clickable). That's it. Double click the file on the desktop called Mathematica and it should work.